# How do I utilize JTA , Persistence and TransactionManager

Tags: java, model-view-controller, persistence, jta

I'm creating a web application, I would like to leverage JTA to do this, can some one direct me to a tutorial or  walk me through the basic to get this done.

The main topics I would like touched on would be:

1. Setting up Persistence
2. Using UserTransaction
3. Setting up proper TransactionManagement

What I assume would necessary to  get this done  (snippet)

```
// My Model/Entity to be inserted into the database

@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Member implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String email;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

With the Entity above and the database specific below, what would my persistence.xml look like ?

- DataBase URL : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
- Driver: MySQL JDBC Driver

Now once I have my perisistence.xml set up , how would I implement a Transaction manager to commit the entity to the database. What am I missing below? How is my TranactionManager associated or connected to my database for lack of better words?

```
public class UserRegistration{
        @Resource
        UserTransaction  transaction;

public void register(Member member) throws Exception {
          try{
                transaction = (UserTransaction)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
                transaction.begin();
                Member member = new Member();
                member.setEmail("test@hotmail.com");
                member.setId(23L);
                member.setName("tester1");      
                transaction.commit();
          }
          catch(Exception e){
          }
    }     
}
```

Comment: I which environment are you running the application?

Comment: @JBNizet Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Service Release 1

Comment: That's your IDE. Do you use an application server? If so, why don't you use EJBs?

Comment: @JBNizet On my local Machine , the war file would be ran on jboss-as-7.1.0 Final. If that answers your question.

Comment: So, use EJBs. They're transactional and use declarative JTA transactions. You don't need to do anything to use transactions: call an EJB method, and you'll have a transaction started and committed for you by the container.

Comment: @JBNizet, Ahh Enterprise JavaBeans, thank you sir , much appreciated.